# How to enqueue Sidekiq jobs and execute them only upon manual launch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails application where I need to enqueue Sidekiq jobs for sending SMS messages. However, I want these jobs to be enqueued but not executed immediately. Instead, I want to have control over when these jobs are executed manually on Sidekiq.

```rb
class Worker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(method_name, *args)
    Services.send(method_name, *args)
  end
end
```

I'm able to enqueue the jobs successfully, but I'm unsure how to prevent them from being executed immediately. I want them to be executed only when I manually run them on Sidekiq or any other tool that i can make

Is there a way to enqueue the jobs in such a way that they remain in the queue without being processed until I manually launch Sidekiq?

Comment: Any queued job will only be run when sidekiq is actually launched.

Comment: On my case i need the jobs when a condition is not met to stay on hold until the condition is true

Comment: Heh, that's quite an important edit :) So yeah, just do what you've done.

Comment: @smathy That works for me now and it's good i've made the change and then changed my question :) ,
maybe i should have replied ?

Comment: Ah, cool. Yeah, that would have been good - to answer your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your goal of pausing SMS notifications and manually controlling their execution, i had to modify my Worker class to check for a flag (e.g., pause_notifications) that determines whether the notifications should be paused. If the flag is set, the job can be rescheduled for a later time.

Here's my current implementation:

```rb
class Worker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(method_name, *args)
    if pause_notifications
      # Reschedule the job to be performed 10 minutes later
      self.class.perform_in(10.minutes, method_name, *args)
    else
      Services.send(method_name, *args)
    end
  end
end
```

In this implementation, when perform is called, it checks the pause_notifications method
If it returns `true`, the job is rescheduled to be performed 10 minutes later using `perform_in`. Otherwise, it executes the `Services.send` method as usual